# PHP replace DIVs and make a tree

Tags: php, html, preg-replace-callback

I would do a HTML tree with divs. All divs have a `padding-left: 5;` as standard to see the trees with its subcategories.

I get the data from a database and want to arrange the categories in a tree. I would like to create a separate DIV for each category. I get out of the database, the parent ID and the ID of the category. So I have to put the categories in the parent category. I would like to make by preg_replace_callback that I extract the pre-existing parent-DIV and then the subcategory insert at the end. Unfortunately this does not work with me, as I would like.

```
Databaseoutput:
Array ( [cid] => 3759 [pid] => 0 [name] => Test 1 )
Array ( [cid] => 3768 [pid] => 0 [name] => Testing 2 )
Array ( [cid] => 3767 [pid] => 0 [name] => Testing 3 )
Array ( [cid] => 3761 [pid] => 0 [name] => Testing 4 )
Array ( [cid] => 3763 [pid] => 3761 [name] => Sub Testing )
Array ( [cid] => 3764 [pid] => 3761 [name] => Sub Testing 1 ) 
Array ( [cid] => 3765 [pid] => 3764 [name] => Sub-Sub Testing 2 )
Array ( [cid] => 3766 [pid] => 0 [name] => Testing 5 )
```

And my code:

```
$code = '<div id="cat_0"></div>';
while ($cat = $db->result()) {
    $code = preg_replace_callback('#<div id=\"cat_' . $cat['pid'] . '\">(.*)<\/div>#Uism', function($match) {
        global $cat;
        return '<div id="cat_' . $cat['pid'] . '">' . $match[1] . '<div id="cat_' . $cat['cid'] . '">' . $cat['name'] . '</div></div>';
    }, $code);
}
echo $code;
```

The result should be:

```
Test 1
Testing 2
Testing 3
Testing 4
    Sub Testing
    Sub Testing 2
        Sub-Sub Testing 2
Testing 5
```

My result that I get:

```
Test 1
    Testing 2
         Testing 3
             Testing 4
                 Sub Testing
                      Sub Testing 1
                          Sub-Sub Testing 2
                              Testing 5
```

I hope you can help me!

Comment: exactly how is this not working for you?

Comment: Can you show us your current result?

Comment: i get **all** divs in PID 0 and not in the right PID-DIVS

Comment: I edited my question and added my current result.